# WP display posts without custom post status

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I need to display my posts without my custom post status (Archive or Featured). But when I write `post_status!= .$status` it doesn't work and it displays all posts.

Sorry for my bad english. but I need help.

```
 function getNewsListings($numberOfListings, $status) {
    $listings = new WP_Query();
    $listings->query('post_type=news&post_status!=' . $status . '&posts_per_page=' . $numberOfListings  );
    if ($listings->found_posts > 0 ) {
            echo '<ul id="news_list" style="list-style-type:none">';
            while ($listings->have_posts()) {
                $listings->the_post();
                $listItem = '<li id="news"><a href="' . get_permalink() . '">';
                $listItem .= get_the_title() . '</a><hr></li>';
                echo $listItem;
            }
            echo '</ul>';
            wp_reset_postdata();
        } else {
            echo '<p>No news found</p>';
        }

}
```

Comment: The query isn't conditions in the same sense as an if-statement. Your `!` is invalid in that context. It's just like a query string in a URL. As far as I know, you can't define "all _except_ this", only "give me this".

Answer (score 0):

try  `'post_status' => 'publish'` in the loop just like that (because if you know what post status you don't want, you should know what you want and you always will have this name):

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'publish' ) );
```

more information:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Status_Parameters

Comment: i understand that. but i need display all posts without posts where status $status

Comment: in the method implementation (https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5.3/src/wp-includes/post.php#L0) there is no way to make that. You need to make some workaround just like taxonomies with negative params: http://www.codeinwp.com/blog/getting-posts-wp_query-class/